# Adding word to names of multiple images in Linux

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu-16.04

I have multiple images in a folder and would like to add a word to all of their names.
Say I have 3 images in the folder

```
A.jpeg
B.jpeg
C.jpeg
```

So I would like the final result to be

```
Afoo.jpeg
Bfoo.jpeg
Cfoo.jpeg
```

The word to be added must be the same and the script must not change the format of the images. Please ask for any details you might need. Thanks.
(image names as code because stackoverflow editor though the names were code)

**EDIT**

All the names are of this format . IF the image NAME has multiple words the they are NOT separated by spaces but are separated by "-" eg- 41. blah-blah.jpeg

Comment: Are all of your names just single character names with the .jpeg extension?  Or do you need the string added right before the .jpeg extension?  Or something else???

Comment: the string can be added anywhere in the name it just needs to be there

Comment: Use: `for f in *.jpeg; do mv "$f" "${f/./foo.}"; done`

Comment: all the names are of this format <number>.<space><nameofimage> IF the image NAME has multiple words the they are NOT separated by spaces but are separated by "-" eg- 41. blah-blah.jpeg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
for img in *.jpeg; do
  mv -- "$img" "${img%.*}foo.jpeg"
done
```

Comment: If my answer is what you want, consider accepting it

Comment: yeah gotta wait 3 minutes

Comment: i bet you want that +15 badly :D

Comment: consider upvoting the questions as well friend :)

Answer (score 1):

Can use `rename` to rename multiple files: `rename 's/.jpeg/foo.jpeg/' *.jpeg`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for filename in *.jpg; do
   firstpart=$(echo $filename|cut -d"." -f1)
   lastpart= $(echo $filename|cut -d"." -f2)
   newfilename=$(echo "${firstpart}foo.${lastpart})
   echo "Renaming $filename to $newfilename.."
   mv -- "$filename" "$newfilename"
done
```

Comment: Also, shouldn't use ls -l in the for loop http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs#line-75